# Database error #1054 using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I think it could be a local server issue because there is nothing wrong with the code. If someone could take a look that would be sincerely appreciated!!

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class Form1 extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('myform1');
    }

    function save(){
        $this->load->model('form1_model');
        if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $this->form1_model->process();                
        }
        redirect('formsuccess1');
    }
}
?>
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
    class Form1_model extends CI_Model {

        function process(){

             $password = $this->input->post('pass_word');
             $passconf = $this->input->post('password_confirm');
             $email = $this->input->post('e_mail');
             $data = array(
                 'password'=>$password,
                 'passconf'=>$passconf,
                 'email'=>$email 
             );

             $this->db->insert('formdata',$data); 
        }
    }
?>
```

**View:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo form_open('form1/save', array('name' => 'myform')); ?>
        <h5>Password</h5>
        <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="password"/>
        <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
        <?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="passconf"/>
        <h5>Email Address</h5>
        <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submittt" /></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your `formdata`(?) table look like? Also, I can't see your form posting either `pass_word`, `password_confirm` or `e_mail`.

Comment: Post your CI backtrace and full error.

Comment: @joachim thankz man itz working now

Comment: Why was this closed? Seems like a genuine question to me?

Answer (score 1):

As @Joachim mentions above in the comments - Your post variable names (`$this->input->post('variable_name');`) need to be the same as your forms input element name attributes.

Instead of `$this->input->post('pass_word');` you should be doing `$this->input->post('password');`.

At the moment you are trying to insert an array of null values into the database.

Also, probably not related to the problem but you shouldn't be accessing post data directly in your model, this should be stored in variables in the controller and passed as parameters of your models `process()` function.

Here is an updated controller and model:

```
<?php
class Form1 extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('myform1');
    }

    function save(){

        // Get your post data here
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $passconf = $this->input->post('passconf');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');


        $this->load->model('form1_model');
        if($this->input->post('submit')){

            // Pass the data to your model
            $this->form1_model->process($password, $passconf, $email);                
        }
        redirect('formsuccess1');
    }
}
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Form1_model extends CI_Model {

    function process($password, $passconf, $email){

        $data = array(
            'password'=>$password,
            'passconf'=>$passconf,
            'email'=>$email 
        );

        $this->db->insert('formdata',$data); 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i got that tanks alot @jeemusu